# How to include my Outlook signature only on new emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Is it possible include my Outlook signature only on new emails and not when I foward or reply? I'm using Outlook 2003.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Head for `Tools > Options > Mail Format > Signatures`.

Then you can choose the signatures that you want to use for new messages and for replies and forwards. You can use a different signature for each. In your case, you should select `(none)` in `Replies/Forwards` box.

Comment: This worked on Outlook 2016 for me too. I was so glad to find this.